# Laravel 5 Auth view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-authorization

I'm working on a laravel 5 project and having some problem using Auth in html.

First i will show my code

**Routes.php**

```
// Router for login
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login_path', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'post_login_path', 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin']);

// Router for dashboard
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

When you go to mysite/login there is a login form
when you fill in the inputs and post it it will go to LoginController@postLogin

**LoginController**

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return view("login.login");
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $gebruikersnaam = $request->gebruikersnaam;
    $wachtwoord     = $request->wachtwoord;

    if (Auth::attempt(['gebruikersnaam' => $gebruikersnaam, 'password' => $wachtwoord]))
    {
        //return JsonHandler::createJsonResponse("Successvol ingelogd redirect...", "/dashboard", "success");
        return redirect('/dashboard');
        //return redirect('home');
    }
    else {
        return "fail";
    }

    //dd(Request::input());
    //return $wachtwoord;
}
```

**User model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    // For custom password field in user table
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->wachtwoord;
    }

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'gebruikersnaam',
        'wachtwoord'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    //protected $hidden = ['gebruikersnaam', 'wachtwoord'];
}
```

When the auth attempt is true it will go to the dashboard. But i can't use the auth fascade in the view.

**dashboard view**

```
<p>Welcome {{Auth::user()->gebruikersnaam}}</p>
```

I will get the following error:

Trying to get property of non-object (View: `C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel5\resources\views\dashboard\master\dashboard-master.blade.php`)

How could i use the auth in my view?
And is this a correct way for logging

Comment: What does your App\User model look like?

Comment: @HansOtt i have added my user model

Comment: I have found the issue. Laravel will use for the user table a primary key called id, but my primary key has a different name. So in the user model a set this:: public $primaryKey = 'user_id'; And know all is working